# Author affiliation with only 1 author

Tags: affiliation, author

I'm using Latex to write professional document where I use the authors and affil fonction.

All is working perfectly when I have 2 or more authors and/or affiliation but for the first time I writing a document with only 1 author & affiliation.

My code is crashing 
Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 128.

My code is simple:
\author{YOU\affil{1}{HERE affiliation}}

Where can I find a solution to stop this error?

All the best,

Mathieu.

EDIT

Here is my \documentclass code

```
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection\quad
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\subsectionmark##1{%
      \markright {%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
          \thesubsection\quad
        \fi
        ##1}}}


\newcount\affilcount
\newcount\saveaffilcount
\newcount\c@fnaffilcount
\def\affil#1#2{\normalsize\affilfont\ \affilcount=#1
\ifnum\affilcount>\saveaffilcount\global\saveaffilcount\affilcount\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname affil\the\affilcount\endcsname\relax
\global\advance\c@footnote by1
\expandafter\xdef\csname affilsymb\the\affilcount\endcsname%
{\the\c@footnote}{$^{\@arabic\c@footnote}$}%
\expandafter\gdef\csname affil\the\affilcount\endcsname{#2}\else
$^{\expandafter\@arabic\csname affilsymb\the\affilcount\endcsname}$
\fi\authorfont}
```

And my code into the document.

```
\begin{document}
\title{yuayuabzabyzuabzyuz}

\author{YOU\affil{1}{BLABLA, BLA, BLA}}
\maketitle
\begin{article}
\section{Headline} ...
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) how are we suppose to help when you do not provide any code for us to try?

Comment: I have edit my question with the code which is problematic I suppose...

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?  Which documentclass is this based on?

Comment: As Sam says, this does not help us much, we still have to guess a lot about your do in order to test.